# Move and rename files from folder to folder as a .bat file and adding modified date at beginning

Tags: batch-file, rename, move, last-modified

I have spent many hours trying to work this out and no luck.

Scenario:
Have multiple different file names, but same extension in a folder. On Windows server 2008 64bit.
Want to move them to another folder using a schedule batch job. .bat. During the move I want to rename them to include their last modified date. I am trying to put into this format:

```
yyyymmddhhmmss-name.zip
```

I have looked at PowerShell and `for` commands and just can't work it out.

I found this 3-line piece of code and it worked well on Windows 7 but not on Windows Server 2008!

```
@echo off
set Date=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
move d:\Test\*.zip d:\Test1\*%Date%.zip
```

On the Server, it could not understand the `*%Date%`. As soon as I removed the `*`, it worked. I have tried different variations with quotes etc. but not working. I understand the date is not the solution I am after, but if I can't get this simple line to work it wouldn't matter with the rest.

Oh and the offsets did work so I got the date to appear `yyyymmdd`. 
I have avoided PowerShell as I am not good with it and I also looked at VBS. But it's not strong points. Can anyone assist?

I know lots of questions are out there similar but nothing quite matches what I am trying to do.

Comment: You say you want to prepend the file's last modified data and time, but your code uses the current date and time. Which do you really want?

Answer (score 1):

WMIC can be used to get the last modified timestamp to fractional second precision. The first 14 characters give the timestamp in exactly the format you are looking for.

Here is a fast solution that does exactly what you asked:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in (
  'wmic datafile where "drive='d:' and path='\\test\\' and extension='zip'" get lastModified^,name'
) do for /f "tokens=1*" %%B in ("%%A") do (
  set "timestamp=%%B"
  set "file=%%~fC"
  set "fileName=%%~nxC"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  move "!file!" "d:\test1\!timestamp:~0,14!-!fileName!"
  endlocal
)
```

The above is finicky if you want to change the requirements. Your WMIC command can take a loooong time if you are not careful, and there are some file masks that simply cannot be emulated with WMIC.

Below is a much slower solution that is very convenient. You pass in the source file mask and destination path as parameters. Assume the script is named "addTimeStamp.bat", then you would use `addTimeStamp "d:\test\*.zip" "d:\test1"`

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "filePath="
if "%~2" neq "" for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ("%~2\") do set "filePath=%%~fF"
for %%F in (%1) do (
  set "file=%%~fF"
  set "fileName=%%~nxF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "skip=1" %%A in (
    'wmic datafile where "name='!file:\=\\!'" get lastModified'
  ) do for /f %%A in ("%%A") do (
    set "timestamp=%%A"
    move "!file!" "!filePath!!timestamp:~0,14!-!fileName!
  )
  endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through the use of `wmic` command. This allows you to obtain current date and time without getting affected by regional settings. At the same time it will also help you to rename the zip file as well.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-6 delims= " %%a in ('wmic path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') do (
    IF NOT "%%~f"=="" (
        set /a FormattedDate=10000 * %%f + 100 * %%d + %%a
        set /a FormattedTime=%%b * 10000 + %%c * 100 + %%e
    )
)

for /f %%f in ("D:\Test*.zip") DO set filename=%%~nf

move "D:\Test*.zip" "D:\%FormattedDate%%FormattedTime%-%filename%.zip"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow  That was a fast reply!

Comment: I added the code in a bat file and modified to point to a different directory, but it fails. get same error as I received 14 hours ago. that is: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.  Interesting that your code and when I entered it is missing the "\" after the word Test in the move command. Is there anywhere else its missing?

Comment: Ahh but its not doing the modified time either. I like what you did though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `FOR` loop and apply the `~t` modifier to the loop variable to access every file's last modify timestamp. You will need to adjust the original timestamp value to the necessary format before actually using it with the `MOVE` command. Here's an example of how you could do that:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%I IN ("D:\Test\*.zip") DO (
  SET lmdate=%%~tI
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  SET lmdate=!lmdate:~6,4!!lmdate:~3,2!!lmdate:~0,2!!lmdate:~11,2!!lmdate:~14,2!
  MOVE "%%I" "D:\Test1\!lmdate!-%%~nxI"
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

It should be noted that the precision of the timestamp returned by a loop variable with the `~t` modifier is limited to minutes, so if you really need that to be seconds, as your post suggests, this may not be a solution for you.

Anyway, this is how the script works.

At every iteration, the `%%I` loop variable is assigned a file name. The `~t` modifier instructs the variable to resolve to the corresponding file's last modify timestamp.

The `lmdate` variable is first initialised with the timestamp as returned by `%%~tI` (the first `SET lmdate` statement) and then the value is rearranged to accommodate to the `yyyyMMddHHmm` format (the second `SET lmdate` statement). Note that, since the original timestamp's format depends on the system's locale, you may need to modify that second SET statement to adjust to your particular system. The above script assumes the following format:

```
dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm
```

The `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExplansion` statement which you can also see above is needed for accessing the actual `lmdate` value inside the loop body. In case you are not aware, "normal" (`%`) expansion of environment variables in block commands doesn't work when the value is set and retrieved in the same command block. That's where delayed expansion comes in handy. You first need to enable it, then use a different expansion syntax (`!`s instead of `%`).

You can see other modifiers used in the script, namely `~n` and `~x` (`~nx` when used together). The former resolves to the file name only (no path or extension) and the latter to the extension only. There are other modifiers as well and they are documented in the `FOR` command's built-in help (`FOR /?`).

Comment: I am happy to go just minutes and not seconds. I am after the files modified time stamps to be in the name. I pasted this script into bat file ran it, but get the usual syntax error. I dont get any error codes. Am I missing something?

Comment: You might be, unless I have. Could you please elaborate on the exact position of the syntax error? Perhaps you could run the script without turning the echo off to be able to see the offending line? I currently cannot see any issue, but I'm still looking into it.

Comment: There was a typo in my posted script. Please try it now.

Comment: Hi Andriy. Same problem. I have pasted the script into a move.bat file. I have removed the echo statement. I still get: The syntax of the command is incorrect. Running in windows 2008 server 64bit.

Comment: Yes, and *which* line does it stumble over, please? Could you post the exact line?

Comment: I cant tell I have rem each line out until only the echo left !

Comment: But that's why I asked you to remove the initial ECHO OFF. When ECHO is *not* turned off, you can see the commands as they are being executed. When an error occurs, therefore, you should be able to see which line caused it.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say I rem ECHO OFF first. I am trying to run the batch job from a dos prompt and I get no lines of code coming up. Its says straight away the syntax is bad.

Comment: Hard to say anything, sorry. Maybe you could manage a screenshot of what's going on when the error happens? Something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iwuY3.png, which is a shot of a complete test run of the script on my PC (no errors there). I'm not sure what specifically I'm expecting to see, but maybe there is something that would reveal the issue if only I could take a look. If that's fine with you, of course.

Comment: Picture says a thousand words. What I did was cut and paste the code into the dos prompt. Immediately it reports it cannot handle the %%I. I took off 1 % from the FOR line, like it appears in your png, and now it runs, but I get the !lmdate! at the beginning of each file and not the actual time.

Comment: Well, the above is supposed to be a *script*, a batch file. Why don't you save it as a `.bat` or `.cmd` file and test it that way? (I'm not even sure if delayed expansion can be enabled/used directly in the command prompt. Maybe it can't and maybe that's why you were getting `!lmdate!`s.)

Comment: Wow. Got it to work in a cmd file. And it works brilliantly. Thats nice coding Andiry, even though I dont understand it. Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have made one PowerShell Script to do exactly what you want.

**Script :-**

```
$src=""      # Source Path of Files to move
$trg=""      # Destination folder
$a=Get-ChildItem $SRC 
IF($a)
{
    for($i=0; $i -le ($a.Count - 1); $i++)
    {
        $fileName=$a[$i].Name
        $fileNameWithoutExtension=$fileName -replace ".zip", ""
        $dirPath=$a[$i].DirectoryName
        $lastModifiedDate=$a[$i].LastWriteTime
        $LMFDate=($lastModifiedDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss");
        $srcFile="$dirPath\$fileName"
        move-Item $srcFile "$trg\$LMFDate-$fileName"
    }
}
```