# Rename files to include last modified

Tags: command-prompt, executable, batch-rename, last-modified

I am attempting to rename a large batch of files to incorporate the dates in the "Date Modified" column from File Explorer into each filename in YYYYMMDD format. I was able to generate a report from the desired file folder of all the files inside using the following steps:

1. Click on the Tips and Tricks folder
2. Hold down the Shift key and right-click the Tips and Tricks  folder
3. Click “Open Command Window Here”
4. Type `dir>filename.txt`
5. Click Enter
6. Open the Tips and Tricks folder and look for a text file with the filename you created

I then pulled the report into Excel as a delimited text file and manipulated the content so I now have the "last modified" date in one column and the filename in another:

> **Date Modified** | **File Name**
>
> 1/9/2009  | ArcGIS_TT_Projections_Transformations.doc
>
> 2/18/2014 | ArcGIS_TT_Re-Projection_WMAS.docx
>
> 1/9/2009  | ArcGIS_TT_Set_Selectable_Layers.doc
>
> 1/9/2009   | ArcGIS_TT_Spatial_Join.doc
>
> 4/21/2010  | ArcGIS_TT_View_CLU_History_Layer.doc

I have only had success using rename scripts like the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in ("ArcGIS_TT_Projections_Transformations*.txt") do (
  set "name=%%F"
  ren "!name!" "!name:ArcGIS_TT_Projections_Transformations=ArcGIS_TT_Projections_Transformations_20090109!"
)
pause
```

But I am trying to avoid having to repeat that process for 61 files so the rename script I have does not meet my needs. Does anyone out there have a suggestion of a Windows CMD prompt or a simple .txt that I can use to pull in the date modified information into the filename more automatically?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: perhaps http://www.cygwin.com/ can give you a decent shell :)
find and xargs are your friends :)

Comment: Related" [Rename multiple files as “Modified Date/Time” using cmd or Powershell](http://superuser.com/a/233197/376602)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move and rename files from folder to folder as a .bat file and adding modified date at beginning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795390/move-and-rename-files-from-folder-to-folder-as-a-bat-file-and-adding-modified-d)